# Speed up docker build process in node application

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, containers

```
FROM buildImage AS stagingBuild
ARG BUILD_NUMBER
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build:prod
RUN npm run ci:tests

FROM nginx:alpine AS staging
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=stagingBuild /scripts/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

am using this file for docker build during my build process. my build process takes place in agent container in dockerIndocker mode.

I need to speed up the process of dockerbuild,so that npm packages download can be avoided,tried changing the base image to a dummy image with npm packages.
12 minutes taken for npm test and another 10 minutes for npm build.
total docker build would take about 25 minutes.
Even tried pulling a previous image before the build process it also didn't help

Docker version 19.03.3, build a872fc2f86

any ideas/Suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to run tests on specifically as part of producing a runnable image, or can a different part of your CI pipeline handle it?  If you're actually using Docker-in-Docker, you'll get a clean Docker daemon on every build and can't take advantage of the build cache; can you use the host's Docker daemon for this instead?

Comment: it would be a clean Docker daemon most of time. Can clean docker daemon be filled with docker image of previous version

can i do a docker pull of previous image version so that npm packages would be taken from the  docker cache.I tried out this but it isnt decreasing the build time.